# Error while deploying python app on heroku

Tags: python, github, heroku

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-fy6uvz1h/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-fy6uvz1h/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-blc65hbn
            cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-fy6uvz1h/
       Complete output (5 lines):
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
           buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-build-fy6uvz1h/setup.py'
       ----------------------------------------
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed

Comment: Can you post the error logs from your dyno in here? You just posted the python error, but not the server log if I understood it right.

Comment: I used github to deploy my app to heroku and these are the only thing which you get while deploying and I'm getting this error